# ImportError: No module named tensorflow can't run Open AI GPT2

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am really bad at coding and for the first time I am trying to run the GPT2 model from Open AI. My teacher was able to run his own model, I tried to do the same with all the right versions for numpy, and tensorlfow, but when I try to  run my own example:

```
python train.py --dataset critique.npz
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 9, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
ImportError: No module named tensorflow
➜  src
```

Should I install a virtualenv ? Sorry if I don't use the right words

Thank you

Comment: Did you install tensorflow in a virtual enviroment? If so, then to import tensorflow you need to have your python script inside the venv. Or check if you have tensorflow installed.

Comment: I already installed tensorflow. I installed all my modules like this:

➜  src pip3 install tensorflow==1.15

Should I uninstall them all, and create the venv like this, and after that reinstall all the modules ?:

$ cd my_project_folder
$ virtualenv venv

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should just install tensorflow, try running:

```
pip install tensorflow
```

Answer (score 0):

I see your problem. If you have installed tensorflow using pip3. Try

```
python3
```

in a terminal and when the terminal opens up with python3, you can check if your tensorflow package is working by running:

`import tensorflow as tf`

If that works then run your py files using `python3 fileName.py`